# Which way to use to work with many objects that use the same methods and

Tags: php

I have some classes, that scrape different websites. They gather data from that websites and return it. 
The returned data always has the same structure. Example

```
name
    => name 
address
    => address
city
    => city
phone
    => phone
```

Now every of these classes extends another class, and gets abstract methods from it. These methods are there to get the data I showed you previously.

Now, I want to get all data from all scrapers. Currently I'm creating an object of every class and then I call that method and then I call again a method to get the collection as array.

The problem is, that the defining of the object variables, the creating and the method calling takes away 150 lines ( I have roundabout 30 scrapers ). So 30 scrapers means

```
30 lines to create private variables
30 lines to create the objects
30 lines to call the method to get the data
30 lines to get the collection as array
30 lines to return the data to the method calling
```

There must be a faster way. Is there any? It would be really helpful! The class that creates all those objects just gets the keyword passed. So I don't determine which directories I should use.

What would your way be to create this?

Comment: Sounds like you are just doing it wrong. Are you allowed to scrape that sites?

Answer (score 0):

Use loops. If you're invoking the same methods on many objects, put the name of the method in an array, and iterate over the array...

```
$fields = array('name', 'address', 'city', ...);

foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $scraper1->$field();
  $scraper2->$field();
  ...
}
```

If your 30 scrapers are also in an array, you can nest two loops:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  foreach ($scrapers as $scraper) {
    $scraper->$field();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple solution. Get theses classes to array and loop it then use **get_object_vars()** and **array_merge()**

It'd be something like this:

```
$objects = array(); // objects that contain data
$data = array(); //array of data
foreach($objects as $o)
   $data = array_merge(get_object_vars($o), $data);
print_r($data);
```

If you don't want to use get_object_vars you can create the abstract method that returns all fields from class and use it in loop.